# Validate h:selectBooleanCheckbox and s:selectItems both on h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, seam

I have two components (`h:selectBooleanCheckbox` and `s:selectItems`).

The `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` has the default value `false` and when it turns to `true` the `s:selectItems` becomes *enabled* so the user can choose any of the options of the list, BUT finally when the user goes to the `h:commandButton` that saves the values choosen, I want to make sure that **if** the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` is `true` (clicked), it has to be obligatory to choose an option of the recently enabled `s:selectItems` component and clicking the `h:commandButton` should prevent processing/saving and tell the user what is missing.

This is the code I have for each component:

[image: components' view declaration]

I have to clarify that this validation is only necessary when the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` is selected/clicked/true otherwise the registration should be performed without problems.

Comment: Sure you don't need the 'seam' tag?

Comment: Where is the button? Post your into a code tag.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the button code, is this: <h:commandButton id="save" action="#{imputacionesPeriodo.saveGastos}"
    value="#{messages['imputacion.horas.impuracionesperiodo.guardar']}" />

Comment: @ChristianCachaya Welcome to SO. Please see: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: And please post code in text, not images